# Using GPU for training DQN agents with TensorFlow in Kaggle notebook: it doesn't work - but GPU quota is decreasing anyway

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, kaggle

I am training an **RL model** based on TensorFlow DQN agent having two NNs both with one hidden layer made of 100 neurons; all in a **Kaggle notebook**. Since it is used NNs and everything is under TensorFlow I take for granted that once the GPU accelerator has been activated in the notebook settings, the training was automatically experiencing the expected acceleration. Besides, the command

`tf.test.is_gpu_available()`

returns

`True`.

Once started the training process I can see that the execution time has not changed and that the only overused resource is the CPU, while both the GPUs are not used at all

[image]

When I've activated the GPU a message said I have to explicitly declare the usage in the code, but I have not found any reference or example on the provided linked page. I gave a glance at the discussions here without finding a clear solution.

Besides and anyway, I can see that even if GPUs are basically not used the GPU quota is decreasing:

[image]

I have read this post https://www.kaggle.com/general/212656 but

```
print("--> Checking for physical Tensorflow devices")

for device in tf.config.list_physical_devices():

    print(": {}".format(device.name))
```

returns

```
--> Checking for physical Tensorflow devices

: /physical_device:CPU:0

: /physical_device:GPU:0

: /physical_device:GPU:1
```

and using

`with tf.device('/GPU:0'):`

"everywhere", meaning before every main block of the code(NNs definition, agent instantiation, training block, etc.) nothing changes. Besides, but this is a secondary doubt, I am not sure that forcing the code to be run on just one of the available GPUs is the proper way to use this calculation resource and the extra memory it should offer.

Comment: You are using two `T4` GPUs instance. Training with multi-GPU requires additional modification, and I highly suspect that *the code you used does not support it naively*. Try changing to a single GPU and run again.

Comment: @Minh-Long Luu thank you I am going to try for sure to test single GPU to see if it works. Anyway that is an option given by Kaggle .... I cannot find any reference in which it is explained what to do in the code for using GPU T4 x 2. Anybody knows?

Comment: You will have to implement [TensorFlow MirroredStrategy](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/distributed_training), which is quite complicated so I do not recommend it. However, unless your RL environment is also running GPU (which I don't think it is if it is inherited from `gym`, [you probably won't find a significant speed boost](https://github.com/DLR-RM/stable-baselines3/issues/472).

Comment: @Minh-Long Luu I have tried also with a single GPU accelerator and it doesn't work. The environment is based on gymnasium ... no way to make it works with GPUs?

Comment: Two things: (1) No, as far as I know, `gymnasium` (which is a successor of OpenAI's `gym`) does not support sampling observations from GPU, so your bottleneck is the sampling speed of the environment. (2) Your network is very small. GPU benefits more from large models and large inputs. If you want to confirm it, consider adding more layers to it to test GPU utilization.

Comment: @Minh-Long Luu you are right: I have exagerated extending my hidden layer network from 1 layer with 100 neurons to 6 layers with this depth fc_layer_params = (32768, 8192, 1024,512,256,128),. Now I can see GPU effort being different than 0%.